# python boto3 error from botocore.compat import OrderedDict ImportError: cannot import name 'OrderedDict

Tags: python, boto3, ubuntu-18.04, botocore

```
>>> import boto3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/boto3/session.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 28, in <module>
    import botocore.configloader
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/botocore/configloader.py", line 19, in <module>
    from botocore.compat import six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/botocore/compat.py", line 28, in <module>
    from urllib3 import exceptions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves import queue
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 96, in __get__
    result = self._resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 118, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 87, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/gti/pysys/req_static/queue.py", line 3, in <module>
    from botocore.config import Config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/botocore/config.py", line 14, in <module>
    from botocore.compat import OrderedDict
ImportError: cannot import name 'OrderedDict'
```

Comment: Is there a `botocore.py` file in your working directory?

Comment: no, that directory is empty.